# Download Video from URL without opening in chrome browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, download, console, html5-video

I have registered for a course that has roughly 150 videos.

**What I have done Uptil NOW:**

There is no download button available right now.
In order to get the URL of each video file, I have created the script which I run through Console as below:

> The site where I am watching these videos is different than the xxxxx marked site.
>   e.g. I am watching on linkedin learning and video is on lynda,etc.

```
console.log(("<h2>"+ document.title)+"</h2>"
+
"<a href=\""+document.getElementsByClassName("video-tech")[0].getAttribute("src")+"> click here </a>");
document.getElementsByClassName("video-next-button")[0].click();
```

an example of output from above code is:

```
<h2>Overview of QGIS features: Learning QGIS (2015)</h2>
<a href="https://files3.xxxxx.com/secure/courses/383524/VBR_MP4h264_main_SD/383524_01_01_XR15_Overview.mp4?V0lIWk4afWPs3ejN5lxsCi1SIkGKYcNR_F7ijKuQhDmS1sYUK7Ps5TYBcV-MHzdVTujT5p03HP10F_kqzhwhqi38fhOAPnNJz-dMyvA2-YIpBOI-wGtuOjItlVbRUDn6QUWpwe1sRoAl__IA1zmJn3gPvC7Fu926GViqVdLa3oLB0mxRGa7i> click here </a>
```

> I have replaced domain name with xxxxx

This way I can get cover all videos without clicking next (I would like to know if I can automate this process by using some timeout techniques as well)
each of this link, when clicked, chrome window looks like below:

[image: screenshot of the window]
this way after **clicking 3dots -> Download,** I can save video individually.

**What I want:**
Method to save all videos without the need to open individually.

Comment: once you have a list of video filenames, you can use wget or curl to download them - you'd be doing that from the console (bash script, powershell, or whatever your OS supports) or if you want to do it via the browser something like https://github.com/jimmywarting/StreamSaver.js/blob/master/examples/media-stream.html will let you write to local disk (but requires more interaction to confirm each filename)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Challenge

To begin with, fetching and saving large binary files is possible when:

- The host server's [CORS](https://www.w3.org/wiki/CORS_Enabled) support is enabled.
- Accessing the host's network from the same [site-origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy).
- Server-to-Server.

Okay, this would reason why your anchor attempt did not work, in fact, accessing the host's network from your localhost will **deny** you from accessing the resource's content unless the host server's CORS support is enabled which is unlikely.

### Workaround

Alternatively, this will leave us with the other two options, accessing from the **same site-origin** in particular due to its simplicity, the strategy lies in executing the *fetching/saving* script from the browser itself, thus, the host server will be gentle with the requests, since they are very similar to the ones coming from the same site.

### Steps

1. Go to the site you wish to download the files from (I used https://www.sample-videos.com).
2. Right-click the web page and select 'Inspect' (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>).
3. Finally, switch to the 'Console' tab to start coding.

### Code

```
const downloadVideos = (videos, marker) => {
  // it's important to throttle between requests to dodge performance or network issues
  const throttleTime = 10000; // in milliseconds; adjust it to suit your hardware/network capabilities
  const domain = 'https://www.sample-videos.com'; // site's domain

  if (marker < videos.length) {
    console.log(`Download initiated for video ${videos[marker].name} @ marker:${marker}`);

    const anchorElement = document.createElement('a');

    anchorElement.setAttribute('href', `${domain}${videos[marker].src}`);
    anchorElement.setAttribute('download', videos[marker].name);
    document.body.appendChild(anchorElement);

    // trigger download manually
    anchorElement.click();
    anchorElement.remove();

    marker += 1;
    setTimeout(downloadVideos, throttleTime, videos, marker);
  }
};

// assuming all videos are stored in an array, each video must have 'src' and 'name' attributes
const videos = [
  { src: '/video123/mp4/480/big_buck_bunny_480p_30mb.mp4', name: 'video_480p.mp4' },
  { src: '/video123/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4', name: 'video_720p.mp4' }
];

// fireup 
downloadVideos(videos, 0);
```

#### ... ahem!

Comment: I tried this, but the source of the video is from another domain(not same as webpage), hence it is opening video URL in same tab and running this code again makes prompt to download. Any modifications I should do?

Comment: @theSwapnilSaste can you clarify what you mean by `makes prompt to download`, also what exactly happens when running the script again in the new tab? can you report back the `Network` tab activity?!

Comment: please check the changes I have made in the post, and tell if I am still required to post the output of the `network tab`

Comment: @theSwapnilSaste Opening the video in a new tab indicates a CORS issue, try to navigate to "https://files3.xxxxx.com" and running the script from there,
also don't forget to change the domain variable to "https://files3.xxxxx.com".